# How to print object content in correct way?

Tags: java, object, tostring

I have an `ArrayList` that contains some objects from `User` class.  When I print these objects I got:

> [User@18fd984, User@18fd984]

How to print these objects in a correct way?

Comment: That is correct--the default Object toString output. Define "correct" for your usecase.

Comment: Object's `toString` returns `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`. You have to override this method for your class per Guido García's answer.

Answer (score 13):

Override the method `toString` in the class to produce the output you prefer, instead of the default value that Java automatically generates. Example:

```
public class User {
   private String name;
   ...
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return name;
   }
}
```

For complex objects, [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) provides some handy methods, if you are already using this dependency in your project:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code of `print(Object obj)` method from `PrintSteam` class:

```
public void print(Object obj)
{
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

and `valueOf(Object obj)` of `String` class:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj)
{
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

As you see, `obj.toString()` is invoked, and as @Guido García states, overriding `toString()` method is what you need.

The default implementation of `toString()` method in `Object` class is as follows:

```
public String toString()
{
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```