# To print the content of object?

Tags: java, println

What changes should i perform in my code so that it could print the whole family
Have tried toString, i am only getting null. This is just a pretty simple code soo plss help.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Alpit on 26-05-2017.
 */
public class Fam {
    String father;
    String mother;
    String sister;
    String brother;
String r;

    public Fam(String father, String sister, String brother, String mother) {
        this.father = father;
        this.sister = sister;
        this.brother = brother;
        this.mother = mother;
    }

    public String getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public void setFather(String father) {
        this.father = father;
    }


}
class add {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String f = obj.readLine();
            String s = obj.readLine();
            String b = obj.readLine();
            String m = obj.readLine();
            Fam fam = new Fam(f, s, b, m);
            arrayList.add(fam);
        }
        for (Object x : arrayList) {

            System.out.println(String.valueOf(x));

        }
    }
}
```

I am only getting the address of Object, This question can be considered to be a duplicate of  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503964/how-to-print-object-content-in-correct-way) but i was not able to understand by the solution provided there.

This is what i tried again

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Alpit on 26-05-2017.
 */
public class Fam {
    String father;
    String mother;
    String sister;
    String brother;
String r;

    public Fam(String father, String sister, String brother, String mother) {
        this.father = father;
        this.sister = sister;
        this.brother = brother;
        this.mother = mother;
    }

    public String getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public void setFather(String father) {
        this.father = father;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return r;
    }


}
class add {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            String f = obj.readLine();
            String s = obj.readLine();
            String b = obj.readLine();
            String m = obj.readLine();
            Fam fam = new Fam(f, s, b, m);
            arrayList.add(fam);
        }
        for (Object x : arrayList) {

            System.out.println(x.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

And this returns null.

Comment: That question explains how to correctly override the toString method and how to get to the desired result. Why do you need us to repeat that information especially for you? Simply read it as often as it takes.

Comment: I tried that,only getting null as output.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include what you tried.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the  toString() method overriding in the Fam class.

Comment: Why do you parameterize your List with Object if you add in Fam instances ?? `List<Fam>` is better.

Comment: OKie i will include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` is given a type parameter of `Object`. This is fine and all, but when you're trying to print the data in the `for` loop, you'll need to cast x to `Fam`. It would be easier to declare it like `ArrayList<Fam> arrayList = new ArrayList<>()`. Also, you can't simply print objects the way you're trying to do it. Object references hold the value of the memory address. You'll need to manually print the data by using the getter methods in your `Fam` class. You could also override the `toString()` method to do this if you want.

Comment: I have changed the list to fam, and overriided the toString(), still getting null.

Comment: Because you're returning a new variable `r` that hasn't even been initialized. In the `toString()` method, you create a string representation of the object. For example, you could put `return father + ", " + mother ", " + sister + ", " + brother`

Comment: Overriding means you can have your input template not printing just a variable. Moreover you didn't assign the r value anywhere.

Comment: srsly this is such a stupid dobut, why didnt it come in my mind earlier. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can override toString() from Object in your Class Fam.

Answer (score 2):

What String.valueOf(object) does is that it calls the toString() method of class Object (in your case it is Fam).

```
 public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

}

So you would need to override the toString() method in Fam class like this:

```
public class Fam {
String father;
String mother;
String sister;
String brother;
String r;
public Fam(String father, String sister, String brother, String mother) {
    this.father = father;
    this.sister = sister;
    this.brother = brother;
    this.mother = mother;
}

.
.
.

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.father +" "+this.mother +" "+ this.sister +" "+ this.brother;
}
```

Additionally, you will need to make this change in your main method.

```
        ArrayList<Fam> arrayList = new ArrayList<Fam>();
```

This way you will get your object printed. (PS: you can change the return format in toString() method.)

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own toString() method.  Do something like this:

```
class Fam {
    String father;
    String mother;
    String sister;
    String brother;
    String r;

    public Fam(String father, String sister, String brother, String mother) {
        this.father = father;
        this.sister = sister;
        this.brother = brother;
        this.mother = mother;
    }

    public String getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public void setFather(String father) {
        this.father = father;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(this.father);
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(this.sister);
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(this.brother);
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(this.mother);

        return builder.toString();
    }


} 

class add {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Fam family = new Fam("father", "sister", "brother", "mother");

        System.out.println(family.toString());
    }
}
```

I have implmented toString() here.  I have used a StringBuilder to demonstrate how you can create your own method, inserting a space between "father, sister, brother, mother".

Running you get:

```
father sister brother mother
```